# Can saltstack use same jid for multi job?

Tags: salt-stack

I intend to get all results of multi jobs by looking up just one jid.
for example:

Two `cmd.run` which will be run:

```
$ salt 'a' cmd.run 'echo "job 1"' jid=1
$ salt 'b' cmd.run 'echo "job 2"' jid=1
```

Then i would like to get consolidated result from `jid 1`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this is not possible. A jid is a unique id for a certain job.

In case the command that you want to execute is something generic that can be executed on host a and b and will return for example "job 1" or "job 2" based on host information you can do something like this:

```
salt -C 'L@a,b' cmd.run C:/get_result.bat
```

If get_result.bat is returning "job 1" or "job 2" based on host information.